# Can't get data from mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I create function to get data from mongoDB by PHP code. But It seem not working well.

let's see my code

```
function updateperformancescore($timepf)
    {
        $mon = new Mongo('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
        $dbs = $mon->selectDB('bitdindatabase');
        $col = $dbs->selectCollection('bd_performance_score');

        $query2 = array("user_ID"=>"999");
        echo "<br>query__".$query2["user_ID"];

        $data2 = $col->find($query2,true);
        echo "<br>count___".count($data2)."<br>";
        echo "check is_object--".is_object($data2)."<br>";
        //echo "--".$data2["user_ID"]."<br>";
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        foreach ($data2 as $obj) 
            {
                echo "aaaa";

                $which = array("user_ID"=>$obj["user_ID"],"time"=>$obj["ps_avgtime"],"slug"=>$obj["lesson_slug"]);

                echo json_encode($which);
            }
```

and webpage show only

query_*999
count*__1
check is_object--1

but my data in mongo is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e768eefbdb8637e2b00c8"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 999, "ps_avgtime" : 999 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e7698efbdb8637e2b00c9"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 998, "ps_avgtime" : 888 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76a1efbdb8637e2b00ca"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 997, "ps_avgtime" : 777 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76a9efbdb8637e2b00cb"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 996, "ps_avgtime" : 77 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76b6efbdb8637e2b00cc"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 995, "ps_avgtime" : 555 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76c0efbdb8637e2b00cd"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 994, "ps_avgtime" : 444 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76caefbdb8637e2b00ce"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 993, "ps_avgtime" : 333 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76d3efbdb8637e2b00cf"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 992, "ps_avgtime" : 222 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76dcefbdb8637e2b00d0"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 991, "ps_avgtime" : 111 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("501e76e6efbdb8637e2b00d1"), "user_ID" : 999, "lesson_slug" : 990, "ps_avgtime" : 1 }
```

Why it's not going into foreach ? And What's wrong with this code and How I get data correctly.
help or guide me please :)

**edit**

I just error_log and It show

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor' in /var/www/web/sendanswer.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/web/sendanswer.php(92): MongoCursor->rewind() #1 /var/www/web/sendanswer.php(343): sendanswer->updateperformancescore(4.4269230365753) #2 {main} Next exception 'MongoException' with message 'The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor' in /var/www/web/sendanswer.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/web/sendanswer.php(92): MongoCursor->rewind() #1 /var/www/web/sendanswer.php(343): sendanswer->updateperformancescore(4.4269230365753) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/web/sendanswer.php on line 92

what does it mean ??

**edit**

That means "Probably your Mongo object is not connected to a database server."

Comment: PHP isn't going to capriciously ignore your foreach. if it's not going in there, then there's nothing for it to go into, meaning your $data2 contains no data.

Comment: How can I check there has data in $data2 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is an error in datatypes.

In database user_ID is an integer,
in your PHP query, it is a string.
Try:

```
$query2 = array("user_ID"=> 999);
```

instead of :

```
$query2 = array("user_ID"=>"999");
```

PHP may be easy on datatypes, but I am not sure about Mongodb and its PHP driver.

Also there is an incorrect parameter in your `find` statement. Remove the `true` as it should be an array of fields, not a `bool`

This code  works correctly :

```
<?php

$mon = new Mongo('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
$dbs = $mon->selectDB('my_db');
$col = $dbs->selectCollection('newColl');

$query2 = array("user_ID"=> 999);
echo "<br>query__".$query2["user_ID"];

$data2 = $col->find($query2);

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
foreach ($data2 as $obj)
{

  $which = array("user_ID"=>$obj["user_ID"],
                 "time"=>$obj["ps_avgtime"],
                 "slug"=>$obj["lesson_slug"]);
  echo json_encode($which);
  echo PHP_EOL ;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
[......]$ php testmongo.php 
<br>query__999{"user_ID":999,"time":999,"slug":999}
{"user_ID":999,"time":999,"slug":999}
{"user_ID":999,"time":339,"slug":999}
{"user_ID":999,"time":339,"slug":5599}
```

Comment: Nothing change.I think we can use "999".

Comment: @crazyoxygen: Actually, "999" (string) is not the same as 999 (integer) .. they are different types in [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) and will not match unless your driver is doing some casting (which the PHP driver does not do, by default).  Try in the `mongo` shell and you won't be able to find id "999" by searching for 999 ;-).

Comment: Oh.You are right but ini php code I change it to 999 and nothing change.

Comment: @crazyoxygen: then probably you've got another bug, although I don't see it at the moment

Comment: @Geert-Jan Another bug was that he was using incorrect parameters in `find` command.